# Server receives request and processes it but Retrofit Android timesouts and fails because of bad internet

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit

I have realized that sometimes when I make a request through Retrofit it fails because of timeout but the server seems to log and insert the data collected. It makes handling retry's very tough (in my perspective as a novice developer) since the same data could be inserted twice or you might have to give the user wrong responses because if failed even though it went through.

Comment: create a service to know the internet connection and the speed and create a function to timeout and work with lifecycle and saveInstance() method to save the data

Comment: @Abdelazizrefaat the internet can still cut in middle of the request right? or should i just ignore and make new request after it timesout... check if already exists and return success like it should... will that be a good thing

Comment: yeah it shouldn't be a problem